# What does the "ved" parameter in a google search refer to?

Tags: html, google-chrome, security, url, google-chrome-devtools

I've spent like two hours or more trying to figure out what a "ved" parameter on a Google search means. A curious person I am.

My finds so far:

$ved value changes-

```
1 - every different search result (diff keywords)
2 - every different resulted block (the url blocks/boxed on the resulted google search, but they are quite similar, as I'll write down below)
3 - every different geolocation perhaps
```

Consider these tests or lookups:

1-
Diff keywords, but first block/position in list:

```
&ved=2ahUKEwidsaSd4M_1AhVlk_0HHUxOCQYQFnoECAsQAg
&ved=2ahUKEwj2pZyN5s_1AhVRmuYKHZ5IB5EQFnoECAcQAg
```

I thought the "ved" value refers to the block/position of a url in the result list, but no.

2-
Twree different urls, first and second from the 1st and 2nd blocks of first page, then third from a "much farther on the list" block:

```
ved=2ahUKEwjq1-Wb1s_1AhW6SWwGHZwpBMwQFnoECD8QAQ
ved=2ahUKEwjq1-Wb1s_1AhW6SWwGHZwpBMwQFnoECCAQAQ
ved=2ahUKEwiZ2NDe1s_1AhVaTmwGHThIA5U4PBAWegQIGRAB
```

3. The same website url, from different countries (not considering blocks or position in list):

   &ved=2ahUKEwiopK2X08_1AhUgxzgGHQEbDkcQFnoECBIQAQ
   &ved=2ahUKEwjpueqC1M_1AhWJq3IEHYEDAfc4FBAWegQIDBAB
   &ved=2ahUKEwih09Wz08_1AhUY7WEKHQYdBB8QFnoECEIQAQ

Very similar they are.

I'd really love to know what they mean. Any ideas are appreciated too!

Answer (score 3):

I found an interesting article explaining the subject : https://moz.com/blog/inside-googles-ved-parameter

TL;DR:

A ved code contains up to five separate parameters, which each tell you something about the link that was clicked on:

- 1st (parameter1: Link index) gives you an idea of where the link was on the page.
- 2nd (parameter2: Link type) is a number that corresponds to the 'type' of the link that was clicked.
- 3rd (parameter7: Start result position) is the cumulative result position of the first result on the page.
- 4th (parameter 6: Result position) indicates the position of your page in the search results.
- 5th (parameter 5: Sub-result position) like the (parameter 6), except it tells you the position in a list of sub-results, such as breadcrumbs, or one-page sitelinks.

Comment: Indeed I've read many articles and posts by now, the one you reffered being one.
Thing is, I assume that "decoding" is many years into the past, probably when google used to have those 9-digit VEDs, but now there seem to be whole lot encrypted in those "logn-digit" veds if I guess right

Comment: You can use this tool to decode them https://valentin.app/ved.html but it is true that there is so little info about this parameter, and I even found that it's not the only one clouded with such mystery, here's a list of unknown google search params: 
    'bav',
    'bvm',
    'bpcl',
    'biw',            
    'bih',            
    'w',
    'h',
    'tbnh',
    'tbnw',
    'fp',
    'ei',
    'usg',
    'sig2',
    'tbs',
    'ved',

Comment: I need to know how to get the 'usg' parameter